# Conditional formatting in Sheets - formatting two cells based on one

Tags: excel, google-sheets, formatting, conditional-statements

I'm working on a personal budget spreadsheet, and I have a tab that calculates what I've spent so far in certain categories and compares that total to what I have budgeted for.  I have one column showing how much I've spent and the one next to it shows how much I have left to spend.  What I want to do is highlight **both** the total and the amount left if the column showing the difference is **negative**.  I want to do this for the whole 2 columns.  Here is a link to my sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AXaxVpVpblxwnS7VBhz4yhz1SNXRGCB6Zrb3OIKiaKk/edit?usp=sharing

I think my main challenge is highlighting both cells dependent on only one of them.  I've tried some custom formulas but they don't seem to work.  I know there has to be a way to do this.  Any ideas?

Comment: Update: I've found a way to do it but it involves applying different formulas to each column.  Also, I'm not sure how to apply this custom formula to all the cells in the column.It'll work but I like the idea of something cleaner.

Comment: Ok I found out I can do a paste special > conditional formatting only. But if anyone can figure out one single formula for this that would be cool! At this point I'm just curious as I feel like I could do it in JS, in theory at least.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fix the custom formula with a $ and apply it to G6:H26 so that when it is applied to column G it still checks column H:-

```
=$H6<0
```

Hope that helps